# Pass GUID to parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How i can pass simple `GUID` value to a parameter `@Param1` in `SSRS`. I have report with couple of parameters and i need to pass `GUID` to one of my parameters

Answer (score 0):

SSRS doesn't understand uniqueidentifiers - it just assumes they are strings.  Just set the value of the parameter to be equal to the GUID you want to pass (preferably in lower case).